# Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts While upload to Google Drive

Tags: php, api

I am using this [Guide](https://www.joellipman.com/google/articles/google/upload-file-to-google-drive-with-php-curl-and-api-rest-v3-without-library-install.html) to upload files automatically to my Google drive and it works fine only with `Simple Upload` method but with `Mulitipart` or `Upload to specific folder` methods always gets this error

```
Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts
```

Here is the full code for Mulitipart method:

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$db_sql = array_map('basename', glob("$dir/*.sql.gz", GLOB_BRACE));
$dbsqlgz_name = $db_sql[0];
$dbsqlgz_path = $dir.'/'.$dbsqlgz_name;
$folder = 'folder_id';

$GAPIS = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';  
global $GAPIS;  
$name = $dbsqlgz_name;
$file = $dbsqlgz_path;
$mime_type = 'application/x-gzip';
$access_token = 'access_token';

$ch1 = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);  

 $my_beautiful_body = '  
--joes_awesome_divider  
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8  

 "name": "'.$name.'",
 "parents": ["'.$folder.'"]

--joes_awesome_divider  
Content-Type: '.$mime_type.'  

'.file_get_contents($file).'  

--joes_awesome_divider--  
 ';   
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $GAPIS . 'upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart');  
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $my_beautiful_body);  
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=joes_awesome_divider', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token) );  

$response=curl_exec($ch1);  
if($response === false){  
 $output = 'ERROR: '.curl_error($ch1);  
} else{  
 $output = $response;  
}  
curl_close($ch1);
return $output;
```

Edit: Added the exactly codes in my php file that run in cronjob as Tanaike requested

Comment: I think that the script in your question works. So can you confirm whether your current script is the same with that in the question? Or if you can provide the script for replicating your issue of `Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts`, please add it to your question.

Comment: @Tanaike the script in my question is exactly the same in my php file

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your script, I could confirm that the script worked and the file could be uploaded. So can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating your issue?

Comment: @ Tanaike Updated my post please check it

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I could confirm that the file could be uploaded by above modification. But if this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. And I apologize for the inconvenience. When I checked your image, unfortunately, in my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. I cannot replicate your situation. By this, I cannot think of the solution. Because I could understand that my answer didn't resolve your issue, I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: No need for apologize you did a great job.